# How to split pandas dataframe using periodic values column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks something like this:

```
v1  v2  v3  result
0  12  31  31       0
1  34  52   4       1
2  32   4   5       1
3   7  89   2       0
4   5  17   8       1
5  11  25  23       1
6   2  32  34       1
7   0   1   3       0
```

As you may note, in the very last column it has a pattern of zeroes and ones.
Is it possible to split this data frame into two sub-data frames?

My desired output will be:

**df1:**

```
v1  v2  v3  result
0  34  52   4       1
1  32   4   5       1
```

**df2:**

```
0   5  17   8       1
1  11  25  23       1
2   2  32  34       1
```

`df.groupby()` will definitely not work, as it will just create two big dataframes;  one with ones, the second one with zeroes. I am not interested in keeping data marked as zeroes.

Thanks in advance!

PS.
In reality this dataframe is much bigger, so I am trying to create df1, df2, ... dfn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
mask = df['result'].eq(1)
a = pd.factorize(df['result'].eq(0).cumsum()[mask])[0]
dfs = dict(tuple(df[mask].groupby(a)))
print (dfs[0])
   v1  v2  v3  result
1  34  52   4       1
2  32   4   5       1

print (dfs[1])
   v1  v2  v3  result
4   5  17   8       1
5  11  25  23       1
6   2  32  34       1
```

**Details**:

Create boolean mask for filtering by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
mask = df['result'].eq(1)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
Name: result, dtype: bool
```

Create counter `Series` by comparing by `0` and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['result'].eq(0).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
Name: result, dtype: int32
```

Filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only `1` rows:

```
print (df['result'].eq(0).cumsum()[mask])
1    1
2    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
Name: result, dtype: int32
```

Add [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) for groups strating by `0`:

```
a  = pd.factorize(df['result'].eq(0).cumsum()[mask])[0]
print (a)
[0 0 1 1 1]
```

Create dictionary from `groupby` object, but also filter rows by boolean mask:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df[mask].groupby(a)))
print (dfs)
{0:    v1  v2  v3  result
1  34  52   4       1
2  32   4   5       1, 1:    v1  v2  v3  result
4   5  17   8       1
5  11  25  23       1
6   2  32  34       1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Flag the rows that will be the beginning of a new dataframe
df['_start_new_gp'] = (df.result == 1) & (df.result.shift() == 0)

# Get rigs of the results = 0 (here creating a copy - not necessary)
df2 = df[df.result == 1].copy()

# Use a cumulative sum on the '_start_new_gp' column to create a "group number"
df2['_group_number'] = df2['_start_new_gp'].cumsum()

# Group by "group number"
grouped = df2.groupby('_group_number')

# Get list of dataframes
dataframes = [group for _, group in grouped]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **`numpy.split`**:

```
s = df.loc[df.result.eq(1)]
idx = np.where(np.diff(s.index)!=1)[0] + 1

for d in np.split(s, idx):
    print(d, end='\n\n')
```

```
   v1  v2  v3  result
1  34  52   4       1
2  32   4   5       1

   v1  v2  v3  result
4   5  17   8       1
5  11  25  23       1
6   2  32  34       1
```